# Save/load Sectioned Recycler View Lists<Object> in shared preferences

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, gson, sharedpreferences

I am using a SectionedRecyclerView to create 2 sections of a shopping list, each item has a checkbox, so one section is for unchecked items and the other for checked items. Each section has a title and a list. I need to save the contents of both lists.

**Section class:**

```
public class HeaderRecyclerViewSection extends StatelessSection{

private String title;
public List<ShoppingItem> list;

public HeaderRecyclerViewSection(String title, List<ShoppingItem> list) {
    super(SectionParameters.builder()
            .itemResourceId(R.layout.shopping_item)
            .headerResourceId(R.layout.section_header)
            .build());
    this.title = title;
    this.list = list;
}
```

I am trying to save one section for now. But when I load the actviity, I get this error:

`Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $`.

Which occurs at the last line of `loadData()` method.

I have researched this error but nothing seems to work for my problem. 
I thought using toJson and putString should work. Maybe I am calling firstSection.list wrongly.

**ShoppingList class:**

```
private RecyclerView sectionHeader;
private SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter sectionAdapter;

HeaderRecyclerViewSection firstSection = new HeaderRecyclerViewSection("Unchecked", getDataSource());
HeaderRecyclerViewSection secondSection = new HeaderRecyclerViewSection("Checked", getDataSource());

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_shopping_list);

    // shopping list with sections
    sectionHeader = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.shopping_listView);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ShoppingList.this);
    sectionHeader.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    sectionHeader.setHasFixedSize(true);

    sectionAdapter = new SectionedRecyclerViewAdapter();
    sectionAdapter.addSection(firstSection);
    sectionAdapter.addSection(secondSection);
    sectionHeader.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);

    loadData();
}


public void saveData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(firstSection.list);
    editor.putString("shopping list", json);
    editor.commit();
}

public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    List<ShoppingItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
    String json = sharedPreferences.getString("shopping list", null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<List<ShoppingItem>>() {}.getType();
    list = gson.fromJson(json, type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

İ think you should use

```
editor.apply()
```

And then while you converting object into json you should put the class as parameter too

```
toJson(firstSection,HeaderRecyclerViewSection.class);
```

Comment: thank you for the reply but I still get the same error

Comment: Ohh my mistake you need to use 'list.add or list.addAll ' to set list.

Comment: where/how do i write that?

Comment: Last line where you get the error as you mentioned in your post. loadData method

Comment: list.add(gson.fromJson(json, type)); cannot be applied to Object.

Comment: List.addAll(gson.fromJson(json, type)); like this but you might get some error with your objects. Also you might have to cast gson.fromJson() into List<ShoppingItem>

Comment: any idea why it is still saying it is an object?

Comment: list.addAdll((List<ShoppingItem>) gson.fromJson(json, type))

Comment: I am deeply suggesting you to improve your java skills. fromJson is a method returns Object type so you need to cast that to a List<yourModel>

Comment: thanks but still the same error :( Yes I know I must improve my java skills

Comment: I still had the stuff from your first answer in, after removing it and doing list.addAll it worked, thank you